Role of mouth size in ability to replicate human phonemes
(If you're uninterested in any of the background info, boiled down question is in the second paragraph)
As part of my worldbuilding, I have become very interested in conlanging; of particular interest to me is the idea of a common language that can be shared between humans and other species, in the societies where they live together.
In this case, I basically have two dragon-equivalent races for which the exact details of their traits are relatively unimportant here; namely, they have snouts and I am likely to place their nasal passage so that it connects to the throat further down and has no relation to the olfactory organs, being a secondary breathing apparatus. The tongues are relatively broad in the back of the mouth but narrow in the front.
Currently, this has led me to exclude most phonemes in the forwards regions (/t/, /n/, /p/, /ð/, etc.), favouring lateral sounds, guttural sounds, and a few simultaneous articulations.
Now, I never had intentions to make these creatures particularly large relative to our typical conception of "dragon"... But I need to know if the size of their oral cavity would have a significant enough effect on the sounds they can make that I would have to stay within a close ballpark of human sized for there to be believable widespread mutual intelligibility. Consider the mouths to be roughly analogous in the regions of articulation, aside from any changes I mentioned above, which are largely elsewhere anyways.

I am pretty certain that a big opera singer such as Luciano Pavarotti was perfectly able to carry on a conversation with a small 4 years old girl... Seriously speaking, it all depends on how the draconic phonatory apparatus works. Why would dragons, who are most definitely not mammals, have a phonatory apparatus built on the same design as humans? For example, we know that tiny birds can produce a good imitation of human speech, and we also know that biggg loudspeakers can do the same.

@AlexP
"Dragon" is vague and isn't intended to be focused on. There are a variety of differences between classical dragons and those I have in mind here, the main point I wanted to get across was that it was a snouted intelligent creature with some superficial similarities.
To a certain degree, I would point to convergent evolution and shared genetic history- tongues, for example, are useful for eating and drinking, but don't necessarily need a specific shape. Vocal cords seem to be a pretty common aspect of earth life as well... is there anything else I'm missing?

"Vocal cords seem to be a pretty common aspect of earth life as well": Nope, not true. For example, even among warm-blooded vertebrates, birds do not have vocal cords, but this does not stop them from producing a large array of sounds. Birds can imitate just about any sound they hear exactly because their sound production is more similar with what a loudspeaker does than with how we do it. In humans, the vocal cords serve to distinguish voiced sounds from their unvoiced pairs, for example to distinguish /v/ from /f/, /z/ from /s/, or /b/ from /p/.

Ah- my bad! You're right, of course. While vocal chords are still a realistic option, I've horribly mangled the matter here.   In a broader sense, which I think was my original intention, sound-producing regions of the respiratory tract are common, and it's reasonable to say that larger organisms would be likely to develop such adaptations for communication as they grew smarter and more social.
Anyways... I do understand how voiced/unvoiced phonemes work. I want to be able to have both for this language, to increase the phonetic inventory a bit, and allow me to include tone in the mix too.

The point is that sound production works in very different ways in different classes of vertebrates, even ignoring invertebrates. For example, the mechanisms of sound production in birds and mammals have literally nothing in common; birds produce sound in a way quite similar to how a loudspeaker works, by inducing vibrations in a membrane or set of membranes; this allows some of them to make just about any sound you can think of. On the other hand, mammals have an entirely different system, where they induce vibrations in a column of air, sort of how a musical wind instrument works.

What I mean to say is that if the so-called dragons, whatever they are, have a sound producing system comparable to an avian syrinx, all the difficulties vanish.

I know! I fail to see the relevance of those details though. It's not super related to my question and the exact mechanism of sound production is kind of arbitrary. I might edit my question actually because including "dragon" seems to have been rather confusing; they aren't reptilian at all, aren't significantly larger than humans, have fur-like feathers rather than scales (at least, the land dwelling species), don't breathe fire, etc.
Anyways; I think bringing up avian sound production could have been really useful... but I really enjoy the idea of working around the anatomical limitations.

You are correct in that this will cause them to have problems with human phonemes. Not insurmountable problems, but problems nevertheless, such as;

By giving them snouts, you just vastly enlarged their mouth volume compared to a human. If the rest of their vocal apparatus is scaled appropriately, your "dragonoids" will naturally speak in rambling bass. Their highest pitched natural voices would be like Darth Vader speaking through a brass tube.
if their tongues (which I assume are reptilian-ish?) are scaled to their snouts, they will almost certainly speak with a lisp. The distance between the back of the throat and the tip of the tongue is just too big to make a proper shape to achieve S-Sounds, C-Sounds, Ts, Ths etc. The only way to fix that is to make their tongues more rigid (like birds have) but this would just replace a lisp with a whistle-like sound. So your dragons would be unable to say "sound", they would say shound, thound, or at best !ound (with he ! representing the sound not dissimilar from a wooden flute).
if the snouts are not just longer, but wider than human mouths, they will experience severe jowl noise.This is a phenomenon where air moves around your back teeth and along the inside of your cheeks, rather than through the wind tunnel between the tongue and the palate. This noise is hard to describe in writing, but its the kind of a wet shhh noise, like a bulldog panting. This will be even worse if their mouths split the whole length of the snout (like a crocodile) without pronounced cheeks to contain the air (like a horse/cow/pig etc).
what about their teeth? Are their teeth humanlike, or reptilian? Are they predators or herbivores? If they have rows of triangular teeth the way crocs or comodo dragons have, it will be difficult for them to properly contain pressure within their mouths when trying to form sounds.

It basically depend on how draconic you want them to be. IF the dragons are just humans with reptilian scales and an elongated face, they might sound human-ish. But the closer to you get to them looking draconic (like say, Argonians from TES) the harder it will be for them to speak human languages.
The most plausible way for them to speak would be very deep guttural bass, and with their lisp masked by replacing difficult sounds with whistling or throat-singing equivalents. So for example, a dragon trying to say "dragon sounds" would instead say "Th(throat warble)aon (!)ounth(!)" in a bass so deep it sounds closer to a truck engine sounds than human speech.

Certainly! This is why I've limited the phonetic inventory. The front of the mouth lacks the same structures as humans have, so they can pronounce /h/, /k/, /ʁ/, /ɮ/ but certainly not /t/, /m/, /s/, or /n/, either due to the tongue not being able to make a seal (too narrow), lack of lips, or whatever fricatives that are available having fundamentally different articulation.
They're omnivores, so would have shearing teeth at the front and grinding ones in the back. Do you think the snout would provide any kind of unusual resonance? The heads aren't too much larger than human, but I'm curious.

@MaxBird that really depends on the size, shape and volume of the snout. Interestingly, this is the kind of a thing you can easily test experimentally. Take a plastic tube (like a cut-off PET bottle) and speak through it. Adjust the length of the tube to fit your idea of what the snout would be like, and you'll get the approx resonance. Of course, a snout would be soft inside, and less resonant, but its the volume that matters most.

Oh! That's actually quite a good idea. Thanks! I'm still in the design process so this might be good to consider.

Frame Challenge
The ability to communicate has less to do with our mouths and more to do with our Brains.
Consider a Parrot - they can whistle phrases that sound perfectly legible: Gizmo asking who let the birds out - but do they understand what they are saying? A Dog can learn commands and learn an association - If X, then Y. They can also Bark, Growl and communicate things to us (Danger! Treats! That Gentleman has 2 Kg of Columbias finest export in his suitcase!)
In order to truly communicate, regardless of the languages, the phonics etc. we need to be able to understand the concepts. Try talking with a 3 year old - they can generally pronounce words, but their ability to understand is limited. Vice Versa - if you have ever had the opportunity to talk to someone exceptionally intelligent - it is difficult because they are moving so quickly between complex concepts that takes you a while to understand and process.
And that is between two native speakers of the same language.
I put it to you that the language itself is 90% irrelevant, it is the brain and the understanding and having your creatures of similar intelligences that is key.

Yes- in this case, both species are roughly equal to humans in intellect and would have similar linguistic abilities. My biggest fear was largely any unforseen complication of the matter... but you bring up a good point. It could be interesting to have certain elements of language process differently for different species; perhaps dragons have less understanding of emotional tone, but a superior ability to discern an exact, literal meaning from language's many nuances that a human might miss... something like "I could" versus "I'm able to."
In any case.. thanks!

To add on to this frame challenge, two species can communicate without issue as long as they can perceive each others' utterances- there's no need to replicate sounds at all. Han Solo and Chewbacca can't speak each others' languages, but they get along just fine. (I believe this is called "receptive bilingualism".) As long as your dragons aren't so large that they speak mostly in infrasound, you should be fine.

@SomeoneElse37 - so like a Geordie talking with a Scouser

@SomeoneElse37- yep! I'm not worried so much about being able to understand it... but I want it to be a language that both species can speak. The idea being that the species codevelop it over a long period of continued sharing of space, resources, community and intellectual volume.
